# unable to compile vim with perl support on linux

Tags: linux, installing

For some reason my Vim won't compile with perl support. Here are my configure options:

```
./configure \
   --with-features=huge \
   --enable-multibyte \
   --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
   --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
   --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7.config-x86_64-linux-gnu \
   --enable-luainterp \
   --enable-perlinterp=yes \
   --enable-gui=gtk2 \
   --enable-cscope \
   --prefix=/usr/local
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem. libperl-dev package was not installed. Need to have it to have perl enabled in vim.

Comment: on alpine this is `perl-dev`